# Conectar Flask Restless API ao React (Admin-on-rest)

Tags: python, rest, react, flask

Eu estou a aprender a trabalhar com flask e react para criar uma rest API(com flask-restless) e um Cliente (com React, Admin-on-rest). Já criei a Api em Flask com o Reastless.

Estou a procura por alguns conselhos para conectar a API ao cliente, mas não consigo encontrar o que eu preciso, se você souber de alguma froma ou tenha alguns truques, por favor diga-me, será muito útil.

Comment: Não encontras nenhuma biblioteca para isso ou tens uma mas não consegues pôr a funcionar?

Comment: eu tenho a API a funcionar, não estou e a conseguir ligar a API ao admin-on-rest, ele não consegue ir buscar a infromação

Answer (score 0):

Ve se isso aqui ajuda amigo

```
<?php
    # Definindo pacotes de retorno em padrão JSON...
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

    # Carregando o framework Slim...
    require 'Slim/Slim.php';
    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

    # Iniciando o objeto de manipulação da API SlimFramework
    $app = new \Slim\Slim();
    $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');

    # Função de teste de funcionamento da API...
    $app->get('/', function () {
        echo "Bem-vindo a API do Sistema de Clientes";
    });

    # Função para obter dados da tabela 'cliente'...
    $app->get('/clientes',function(){

        # Variável que irá ser o retorno (pacote JSON)...
        $retorno = array();

        # Abrir conexão com banco de dados...
        $conexao = new MySQLi("SERVIDOR","USUARIO_SERVIDOR","SENHA_DO_USUARIO","BANCO_DE_DADOS");

        # Validar se houve conexão...
        if(!$conexao){ echo "Não foi possível se conectar ao banco de dados"; exit;}

        # Selecionar todos os cadastros da tabela 'cliente'...
        $registros = $conexao->query("select * from cliente");

        # Transformando resultset em array, caso ache registros...
        if($registros->num_rows>0){
            while($cliente = $registros->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH)) {
                $registro = array(
                            "CODIGO"   => $cliente["CODIGO"],
                            "NOME"     => utf8_encode($cliente["NOME"]),
                            "TELEFONE" => $cliente["TELEFONE"],
                            "EMAIL"    => $cliente["EMAIL"],
                        );
                $retorno[] = $registro;
            }
        }

        # Encerrar conexão...
        $conexao->close();

        # Retornando o pacote (JSON)...
        $retorno = json_encode($retorno);
        echo $retorno;

    });

    # Executar a API (deixá-la acessível)...
    $app->run();
    ?>
```

Em tempo, para o pleno funcionamento desses métodos, precisamos criar e incluir mais um arquivo na pasta api. Por isso, crie um novo arquivo no Notepad++, salve-o como .htaccess e insira o seguinte código-fonte:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Agradeço muito o comentário, mas como eu estou a utilizar python não sei como conseguir utilizar esse código para o que preciso neste momento. Mas vou guarda-lo pois poderei utiliza-lo num futuro próximo para a minha empresa

Comment: estava aqui a ver outra vez o código que me enviou e fiquei com uma duvida, isso não dará para conectar com react, servindo de intermediário entre o flask e o react

Comment: verdade amigo não dará mesmo, vou pensar em uma outra forma aqui

Comment: Obrigado! Quando conseguir alguma coisa diga!